# Unexpected SwiftUI @Binding behavior

Tags: swiftui, binding

I have  the following SwiftUI `View` (shortened):

```
struct ItemTextField: View {
    @Binding var textFieldText: String
    @Binding var currentMode: DisplayMode

    var body: some View {
            PresetTextField(defaultText: "Enter item name", 
                            presetText: dataSource.nameOfEditedViewItem == nil ? textFieldText : dataSource.nameOfEditedViewItem!, 
                            textFieldText: $textFieldText)
            .onChange(of: textFieldText) { newtext in
                textFieldText = newtext
                // …
                currentMode = textFieldText.isEmpty ? .addingItems : .enteringItemName
            }
    }
}
```

This `ItemTextField` is used in a `View` as follows:

```
    @State private var currentMode: DisplayMode = .displayingItems
    @State private var textFieldText = ""  
    // …
    ItemTextField(textFieldText: $textFieldText, 
                  currentMode: $currentMode)
```

When a breakpoint at instruction `currentMode =` is hit, the debugger shows me the following values:

```
Printing description of self._currentMode:
▿ Binding<DisplayMode>
  ▿ transaction : Transaction
    ▿ plist : []
      - elements : nil
  - location : 0xe000000000000000 <x-coredata:////p4293263453814>
  - _value : ShopEasy_.DisplayMode.displayingItems
```

and

```
(lldb) po currentMode
ShopEasy_.DisplayMode.addingItems
```

After a single step, i.e. after executing instruction `currentMode =`, the debugger shows me the following values:

```
Printing description of self._currentMode:
▿ Binding<DisplayMode>
  ▿ transaction : Transaction
    ▿ plist : []
      - elements : nil
  - location : 0xe000000000000000 <x-coredata:////p4293263453814>
  - _value : ShopEasy_.DisplayMode.displayingItems
```

and

```
(lldb) po currentMode
ShopEasy_.DisplayMode.enteringItemName
```

Obviously, `self._currentMode` and `currentMode` are different items, but why? I thought `@Binding` would bind the local item to the passed item.
How to do it right?

Comment: `currentMode` is the property wrapper's wrapped value and `self._currentMode` is the property wrapper. So you could try `po self._currentMode.wrappedValue` that should be the same as `currentMode`

Comment: @user1046037 You are right, this gives the same value. But what is wrong with my code, or better: how to modify it to change the bindet item?

Comment: You can see the same behaviour with @State as well. Any property wrapper would hide some implementation detail and shows something on the outside. Refer: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html (check the section under property wrapper)

Comment: I am aware of this. What I want is to change the passed item, which should be possible using @Binding. But this seems not to happen.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question fully. if you want to set a new binding you can do that by assigning a binding to `_currentMode`. `_currentMode` will be `Binding<DisplayMode>` and `currentMode` will be `DisplayMode`

Comment: Can you try a simple print statement and see if you are getting the result you expect

Comment: I am sorry that my question was not clearly enough formulated. Maybe this explains it better: I have a `View` with a `@State var currentMode`. This `var` is passed to an `ItemTextField` that has a `@Binding var currentMode`. Within `ItemTextField`, `currentMode` is set. I expected that this setting is propagated to the `@State var currentMode`. Appatently, this is not the case, and I don't understand what is wrong with my code. I hope this makes the situation clearer!

Comment: `@State` is ideal for states private to the view, so it's not a good idea to pass it around. In your case your could create a `ViewModel` as a `@StateObject` in your parent view. Let the `ViewModel` contain a property called `currentMode` that you can pass as a binding to your `ItemTextField`. That way your parent view can access the value and `ItemTextField` can set the value. Otherwise `EnvironmentValue` could serve this purpose as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, and you may be right with your suggestion. The only thing that worries me is that - apparently - my code is exactly as the example in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding). So why does it not work?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong, it is possible, would it be possible to simplify your code to a minimum reproducible code to test it and see what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

By now I believe this is a bug in lldb. As suggested by @user1046037, I wrote the following minimum project:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var state = false
    var body: some View {
        ButtonView(state: $state)
    }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    @Binding var state: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("State: \(state ? "true" : "false")") {
            state = true
        }
    }
}
```

This code works as expected, i.e. `state` is changed in the Button action.
Then I set a breakpoint at `state = true`. Here is the debugger output
before executing the assignment

```
Printing description of self._state:
▿ Binding<Bool>
  ▿ transaction : Transaction
    ▿ plist : []
      - elements : nil
  ▿ location : <LocationBox<ScopedLocation>: 0x6000016895c0>
  - _value : false
(lldb) po state
false
```

and after the assignment

```
Printing description of self._state:
▿ Binding<Bool>
  ▿ transaction : Transaction
    ▿ plist : []
      - elements : nil
  ▿ location : <LocationBox<ScopedLocation>: 0x6000016895c0>
  - _value : false
(lldb) po state
true
```

This indicated to me that simply the lldb output is wrong, while the code works correctly.